# what happen between after notify_all() and before wait() get the lock?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, condition-variable

I test the `std::condition_variable` using the below code:

```
class CondWait{
public:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mu;
    int i=0;
public:
    void mainTask(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
        cv.wait(lk);
        i++;
        std::cout<<"main task, "<<i<<std::endl;
    }
    void notifyTask(){

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
        i = 0;
        std::cout<<"notify task, "<<i<<std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();
        std::cout<<"notify task, sleep 5 sec"<<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }
};
int main()
{
    CondWait condwait;
    std::thread t1(&CondWait::mainTask,&condwait);
    std::thread t2(&CondWait::notifyTask,&condwait);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes, the output is below and the program is blocked:

```
notify task, 0
notify task, sleep 5 sec
```

Sometimes, the program will run well,i.e. after 5 seconds of sleep, it will output `main task, 1`, the complete output is:

```
notify task, 0
notify task, sleep 5 sec
main task, 1
```

In my opinion, int the `notifyTask` thread, the mutex is still used after `notify_one`, so the `wait` in the `mainTask` cannot lock the mutex. But I don't know what will happen next, why the example will have an ambiguity performance. Could you please provide some advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you start both threads concurrently perhaps a situation occurs when  `cv.notify_one()` is called before `cv.wait()` in `mainTask` and since no threads are waiting yet, the function **does nothing**. After that, `wait()` is executed and hangs waiting for a notification

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I add a delay between the creation of two threads. The result verified your answer is right. I want to ask further why the `wait()` can wait until the `notifyTask` release the lock. I think `wait` should try to get the lock once the `notify_all()` executed.

Comment: `wait` tries to acquire the lock immediately after being notified, but has to wait until `notify` thread release it by finishing. `notify_one` does not release it itself

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Thank you very much!