# Calling std::condition_variable::notify_one() multiple times before std::condition_variable::wait() is called

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

I am struggling to understand the way `std::condition_variable` is used. Let's say I have Producer and consumer thread and both are operating on same `condition_variable`. Producer fills the data to process very fast and calls `std::condition_variable::notify_one()` every time a data is pushed to container. So let's say Producer pushed 10 items and called `notify_one()` 10 times even before consumer can process data that was added first. Now producer thread exits so it will not call `nootify_one()` anymore so what will happen to consumer thread who is waiting on `condition_variable`? Will previous 9 calls to `notify_one()` will be queued and consumer will be unblocked 9 times more?

Comment: In the producer/consumer the consumer should wait until the queue container is not empty. std::condition_variable is just a way to suspend consumer thread while there's no work and resume it on the signal from producer thread.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636456/what-happen-between-after-notify-all-and-before-wait-get-the-lock/

Comment: but why it exits without `join()` or so? ...And notification is received anyway whatever waiting thread can do something or not. it can flip some of its flag vars  and then check it.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one),

> **If any threads are waiting on *this**, calling notify_one unblocks one of the waiting threads.

The thing is, it shouldn't matter. Any consumer using the condition_variable must check if they are allowed to proceed, that is, if there's any available data.
In the case you describe they'll find there is, so they won't be suspended and won't require the notification.

Or, said in the other way, they'll be suspended when no data is available, and will wake up only after the producer adds new data and calls `notify_one` with any suspended consumer.

Comment: So that means if I check for something like below it will work ?   m_conditionVar.wait(lck, [this]() {return !m_dataQueue.empty() || m_isQueueWriteCompleted ;}      But documentation says m_conditionVar.wait() will block until notify_one/all is called?

Comment: You got it, @AnandShah . Take a look at the [documentation page for `wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) . See the little `while (!pred()) { wait(lock); }`snippet? The wait only happens if at the time of the call there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`condition_variable::notify_one()` and `condition_variable::notify_all()` do **not** record the number of times they've been called. They apply to any threads that are waiting at the time of the call. Threads that wait for the condition variable later are not affected by previous calls. It's up to the program to keep track of whether there's any work pending.

That's why `wait()` is called from a loop:

```
while (no_data_ready())
    myvar.wait();
```

That is, only wait when there's nothing to do.